# Substitutions of translations with source files strings

Tags: php, wordpress, internationalization, wordpress-theming, po

Our team prepared the theme for wordpress which had some hard-coded text implemented. Based on the strings in "_e()" functions we generated po and mo files. After preparing two translations (one of which is English one), it occurred to us, that we have to outsource translating. However for that, we need our source translation to be in English, and strings that are hard-coded are in other language.

First question is: is there a fast way to substitute all strings in our theme's source files, that are in functions "_e()", with the strings from English translation (po and mo files). The best solution would be if it wouldn't break one other translation that we have already prepared.

Second question is: is there any other way, we can pass translators the po files which have English as a source language, and then somehow load it in our wordpress theme, although strings in "_e()" does not match source language of po files?

Comment: You could perhaps have a look at this tool for a different approach:
http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/poswap.html

Comment: Ok, but does it work with wordpress?